# how to update element height dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom, height

I am dynamically adding elements to a div which automatically adjusts it's height.
All is working well except with Android browser 4.1 >  ( haven't checked lower yet.. )

The div will only adjust the height on the first append.

I added kind of a hack to get the browser to readjust the height:

```
   wrapperType.css({ "overflow" : "auto" }) 
   wrapperType.css({ "visibility" : "hidden" })
   setTimeout( function() { wrapperType.css({ "visibility" : "visible" }) },0);
```

and it works, but there's a flicker every time. 
Is there a better way to force a DOM recalculation than what I'm doing?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please. What code do we need to replicate the issue?

Comment: is the element positioned absolutely or fixed ? Why do you need to adjust height in such a way :S ?